# What mission do you have to complete so you can rob Marcus?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have heard that after you complete a mission, you are teleported back to Sanctuary in a room full of loot chests. What mission do you have to complete for this to happen? (I have already completed the game but I forgot this for TVHM)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to complete the story mission *Where Angels Fear to Tread*.

Spoiler:

> After you talk to Roland and start part 2 of this mission, a cutscene will play and Lilith will teleport you to Marcus' store room in Sanctuary.